# Proving the $L$ function approaches a square...

Tags: real-analysis, limits, definite-integrals

Lets say that $$L(n)=2\int_{-1}^1 \sqrt{1-x^n}\space\text{dx}=4\text{?}$$

It seems that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} L(n)=4$$

Why 4? That number is the size of a square with diameter 2.

Check out what I mean, here on W|A is $L(2),L(20), L(200)$

[$L(2)$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2*%28integral%20from%20-1%20to%201%20of%20sqrt%281-x%5E2%29%29%20)

[$L(20)$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2*%28integral%20from%20-1%20to%201%20of%20sqrt%281-x%5E20%29%29%20)

[$L(200)$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2*%28integral%20from%20-1%20to%201%20of%20sqrt%281-x%5E200%29%29%20)

You can graph the functions on Desmos and see the approach.

So, how can you prove this limit?

Comment: Heuristics: $L(2)$ is the area of a unit circle; the graph of the map $x \mapsto \sqrt{1 - x^{n}}$ on $[-1,1]$ approaches to a square as $n$ grows indefinitely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside $(-1, 1)$, $x^n$ converges pointwisely to the zero function, so as $\sqrt{1-x^n}$ is bounded by $\sqrt 2$, the [bounded convergence theorem](http://www.math.toronto.edu/lguth/acepabct.pdf) implies that 
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} L(n) = \lim_{n\to \infty} 2\int_{-1}^1 \sqrt{1-x^n} dx = 2\int_{-1}^1 \lim_{n\to \infty} \sqrt{1- x^n} dx = 2\int_{-1}^1 1\ dx = 4.$$

Comment: For odd $n$, $\sqrt{1-x^n}$ is not bounded by $1$, but by $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: @mickep : Thanks. Edited.